# PDFJS in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2, pdf.js

Can any one explain how to add pdfjs in ionic2 project so we can import and use it.Thanks.

I know how to use pdfjs but I am not enable to find any way how to import it in ionic2 project

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps I followed to integrate pdfjs in ionic2.**

```
1 . I created a lib folder inside app folder of ionic2 project and
copied all the pdfjs library files such as js, image, css and html
file inside  lib folder.

2. Wrote a gulp task to add these files into the www > build folder.
```

These steps will add the pdfjs to ionic2 project.

**Steps to use it inside a typescript**

```
openPdf(): void {

        var _self = this;

        setTimeout(() => {

            this.pdfjsframe = document.getElementById('pdfViewer');

            if (this.pdfjsframe != null) {
                this.pdfjsframe.onload = function () {
                    _self.loadPdfDocument();
                };
            }

        }, 0);
    }

    loadPdfDocument() {
        var pdfData = this.base64ToUint8Array(this.fileBase64);
        this.pdfjsframe.contentWindow.PDFViewerApplication.open(pdfData);
    }

    base64ToUint8Array(base64) {
        var raw = atob(base64);
        var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(raw.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
            uint8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return uint8Array;
    }
```

**Html For displaying PDF**

```
 <div id="frameContainer" class="pdfViewerContainer" *ngIf="isPdf">
    <iframe id="pdfViewer" src="build/viewer.html" class="pdfViewerFrame" allowfullscreen> </iframe>
  </div>
```

**css**

```
.pdfViewerContainer
{
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px !important;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.pdfViewerFrame
{
    width:100%;
    height: 93.5%;
}

.viewerNavbar
{
    position: relative; z-index: 2;
}
```

css require some improvement

Note: I have made changes in viewer.js open method to expect the byte array as input parameter

Answer (score 0):

I use pdfjs in one project and this is what I did:
- I save pdfjs.js in my assets folder.
- I import it from src/index.html

```
<script src="assets/js/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

- I use it in my code declaring. In my case I´m using it in a service / provider to reuse in any part of my app injecting it.

```
declare let jsPDF;
```

After you can use without problem:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFontStyle('bold');
doc.text(20, 20, "Parte de Trabajo Número " + serieId);
doc.text(20, 30, "Cliente: " + parte.nombre);
doc.text(20, 40, "Fecha: " + parte.fechaformato);
doc.text(20, 50, "Horas: " + parte.horainiformato + ' a ' + parte.horafinformato);
```

Comment: pdf is not being export when i am installing this on android as an apk, i see my downloads folder and there is no pdf generated, but it works on browser..what can be the issue ? please guide